# Algorithm in Python equivalent to Q to manually generate identity matrix

Tags: python, numpy, kdb, array-broadcasting

I know about `np.eye` which generates identity matrix. This question is about the algorithm rather than about the final result.

In Q (kdb+ language) I can generate identity matrix using the following code:

```
`float${x =\: x} til 12000
```

Python numpy equivalent is more or less this:

```
import numpy as np
r=np.arange(12000)
np.asarray([i==r for i in r]).astype(float)
```

With Python approach there's an unnecessary data copying during `np.asarray` to convert Python array back into numpy array. Is there a way to avoid this copying? I.e. I want  to perform `[i==r for i in r]` without getting out of `numpy` domain.

Comment: why do you want to do this?  presume it's part of a bigger problem, but difficult to know what to optimise for

Comment: It's just an exercise, there's nothing more to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [822]: r=np.arange(4)
```

Your list comprehension:

```
In [823]: [i==r for i in r]
Out[823]: 
[array([ True, False, False, False]),
 array([False,  True, False, False]),
 array([False, False,  True, False]),
 array([False, False, False,  True])]
```

A broadcasted array equivalent:

```
In [824]: r[:,None]==r[None,:]
Out[824]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

another array approach:

```
In [825]: A = np.zeros((4,4),int)
In [826]: A[np.arange(4),np.arange(4)] = 1
In [827]: A
Out[827]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

or  (inspired by the code for `np.tri`):

```
In [831]: np.equal.outer(np.arange(4), np.arange(4))
Out[831]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to generate the unit matrix in the most efficient way, I would recommend the following trick:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> e = np.zeros(n*n)
>>> e[::n+1] = 1
>>> e.reshape((n, n))
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```